# how to delete extra space of images on grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a group of imaged to be grid. but they have extra spaces around them.
i controlled padding and margins ,vertical align changes and display block options but  neither of them seems to be the solution.

this image is what i get

[![Current result][1]][1]

```css
.event-container{
margin-top: 10%;}

.event-img-wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;}
.a {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;}
.b {
  grid-column: 3 ;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;}
.c {
  grid-column: 1 ;
  grid-row: 2 ;}
.d {
  grid-column: 2 ;
  grid-row: 2 ;
   width: 10%;}
.a img{
  max-width: 600px;}
.b img{
  max-width: 400px; }
.c img{
  max-width: 300px;}
.d img{
  max-width: 350px;}
```

```html
<div class="container event-container">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-1">
                <span class="services-title">
                        گروه بزرگ کاوه استیل </p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="event-img-wrapper">
              
            <div class="box a">
                <img src="../assets/images/آهن-770x480@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box b">
                <img src="../assets/images/89879@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box c">
                <img src="../assets/images/ahhann-2@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box d">
                <img src="../assets/images/images (5)@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap flex it's gonna help you to have tidy gallery

Comment: Can you check if you have removed the image link? It was coming before, now it is not

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Hope, this can help

```html
<style>
.event-img-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 0;
    grid-row-gap: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 22vw);
}

  .event-container{
    margin-top: 10%;
  }


  .box {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .a {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .b {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  .c {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .d {
    grid-column: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>


<div class="container event-container">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-1">
                <span class="services-title">
                        گروه بزرگ کاوه استیل </p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="event-img-wrapper">
              
            <div class="box a">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1452827073306-6e6e661baf57?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box b">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597910037283-e728413e079c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box c">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526336179256-1347bdb255ee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box d">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" align="left"/>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the space between columns is because of `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3fr;`

Fr is a fractional unit. The Fr unit is an input value that automatically calculates layout divisions when adjusting for gaps inside the grid.

run the code snippet and change values for the above property to see different amounts of space around the containers.

```css
.event-container{
margin-top: 10%;}

.event-img-wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 3fr;}

.box {
  border-radius: 5px;}
.a {
  grid-column: 1;}
.b {
  grid-column: 3 ;
  grid-row: 1;}
.c {
  grid-column: 1 ;
  grid-row: 2 ;}
.d {
  grid-column: 2 ;
  grid-row: 2 ;}
```

```html
<div class="container event-container">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-1">
                <span class="services-title">
                        گروه بزرگ کاوه استیل </p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="event-img-wrapper">
              
            <div class="box a">a
                <img src="../assets/images/آهن-770x480@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box b">b
                <img src="../assets/images/89879@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box c">c
                <img src="../assets/images/ahhann-2@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box d">d
                <img src="../assets/images/images (5)@2x.png" align="left"/>
            </div>
            </div>
```